# How to use Ninject in a Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ninject

I have an WinForms application with this Main Form :

```
    ICountRepository countRepository;
    public MainForm(ICountRepository countRepository)
    {
        this.countRepository = countRepository;
    }

    public void IncrementCount()
    {
        countRepository.IncrementCount();
    }
```

but i am struggling to inject `ICountRepository` into the mainform. How do I do that ?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937187/does-di-make-sense-in-a-desktop-app

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well the first steps are to switch from:

```
var form = new MainForm();
Application.Run(form);
```

to:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel( new ModuleRegisteringICountRepository());
var form = kernel.Get<MainForm>();
Application.Run(form);
```

Perhaps a clarifying edit or two about what sort of thing you're looking to achieve might get you a more detailed answer.

---

Highly recommended to get up to speed with the patterns around this is @Mark Seemann's [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://manning.com/seemann) book (in it's parlance, the transformation above makes `Main` your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) - the (single) `Get` [Composes the  object graph](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/)  of your app.

Comment: i finally did this inside the main method in the Program.cs file.